# Problema al ejecutar un archivo en terminal Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, terminal

tengo un problema al tratar de ejecutar un archivo de texto desde la terminal Ubuntu.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ejecutando este comando:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Pues claramente te esta diciendo que la argumento `-a` no es valido

Answer (score 2):

La sintaxis:

```
open -a "<aplicación>" <archivo>
```

Se usa en la terminal de Mac OS, por tanto no te va a servir en Linux.

Por razones históricas el comando `open` en Linux está reservado para un propósito diferente. El comando que estás buscando puede ser [`xdg-open`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xdg-utils#xdg-open), en linux lo puedes usar así:

```
xdg-open calculos.txt
```

Sin la opción `-a`. Si quieres especificar la aplicación con la que quieres abrir el archivo debes indicar el programa que quieres ejecutar seguido del nombre del archivo. En ubuntu tienes disponible el editor (blog de notas) [gedit](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Gedit), para abrir tu archivo con este editor puedes usar el comando:

```
gedit calculos.txt
```